# boolean always returning true

Tags: java, boolean

I am currently learning Java. I am making a program that fetches the html code of a given URL, which then saves the code as *.html. At the end of the code, I am trying to print a message as to whether the file has saved or not.

My problem is that the boolean that determines if the file has saved always returns true.

Here is my code:

```
public class URLClient {
protected URLConnection connection;

public static void main(String[] args){
    URLClient client = new URLClient();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String urlInput;
    String fileName;

    System.out.print("Please enter the URL of the web page you would like to download: ");
    urlInput = input.next();

    System.out.println("Save file As: ");
    fileName = input.next();


    String webPage = client.getDocumentAt(urlInput);
    System.out.println(webPage);
    writeToFile(webPage, fileName);

}

public String getDocumentAt (String urlString){
    StringBuffer document = new StringBuffer();

    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            document.append(line + "\n");
        reader.close();
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to URL: " + urlString);
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("IOException when connectin to URL: " + urlString);
    }

    return document.toString();
}

public static void writeToFile(String content, String fileName){
    boolean saved = false;

    try{
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

        try{
            writer.write(content);
                   boolean saved = true;
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Caught exception while processing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (saved)
        System.out.print("Successfully saved " + fileName + ".html");

}
```

}

The boolean is called "saved" and is in the writeToFile() method.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The inner `saved` should not have `boolean` in front of it. You are putting the outer `saved` out of scope, which is temporarily shadowed. `saved = true` rather than `boolean saved = true`.

Comment: Remove `boolean` before `saved` inside `try`

Comment: Remove `boolean` from `boolean saved = true;` but don't you use any IDE ? because this should indicate you a compilation error

Comment: @pickypg: Right suggestion, wrong explanation. The code in the post won't compile due to the duplicate local variable `saved`.

Comment: @KyleWilson: why do you think it should ever be `false`?

Comment: @jlordo Good catch. Guess I have my languages mixed up. Too much Javascript recently :)

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    writer.write(content);
    saved = true; // no need to initialize again
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: I don't disagree with the bug, but that doesn't explain why it always returns *true*: his code would always return false. I suspect this title is incorrect... :/

Comment: @Bohemian: why would it ever be `false` (as long as there is no `IOException`)?

Comment: @jlordo OP's code, not code in answer

Comment: @jlordo `saved` will always be `false` in OP's code because of `boolean saved = false;` is never changed (the new local var `saved` inside the loop is always true)

Comment: @Bohemian: There is no loop in OPs code. The `boolean saved = false;` inside the `try` block in his `writeToFile()` method is not a new local var, it's a compiler error due to the duplicate local variable `saved`.

Comment: I hadn't noticed I was initializing saved twice :S This must have been while I was moving "boolean saved = false" about, trying to initialize it in the right place.

Thanks for your help, lesson learned ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to understand the concept of Local and Global variables. You have initialized two times the same variable name with same datatype. I have changed the code accordingly for you.

```
public static void writeToFile(String content, String fileName){
boolean saved = false;

try{
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

    try{
        writer.write(content);
        saved = true;
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Caught exception while processing file: " + e.getMessage());
}
if (saved)
    System.out.print("Successfully saved " + fileName + ".html");
}
```

Comment: The top `saved` is not a global variable.

Comment: @pickypg The first line just make it clear to user to learn what thing first. I know it not Global but in context to a method it can be considered as Global from method level and considered Local from Class level.

Comment: Local to a `class` would be a field/member, which would be more akin to a global for an instance method.